# All iOS Provisioning Profiles stuck at pending

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I'm attempting to create new iOS Provisioning Profiles, but as I create them the Apple website hangs as I submit the 'Name the profile and generate' page.

Returning to the list of profiles I can see the new profile but it remains at 'Pending' and does not allow me to use it.

I'm using Xcode 5 and hitting refresh on the Accounts preference pane does not delete the old profiles, or make any change to the pending profiles online.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have met similar problem: I wasn't able add new devices. Then I tried to use Safari instead Chrome. It's helped.

Comment: @Eat A if it's wrong please delete the post. grant me permission for ask question i unable to ask to question. Help me..

Comment: if it's wrong please delete the post. grant me permission for ask question i unable to ask to question. Help me..

Answer (score 5):

Clear your browser cache and try again. Also use Safari instead of other Browsers as apple dev portal plays always better in safari.

Lots of times devices are actually added, so if you refresh the web page you will see them there.

Comment: Nikos solutions works!!

Comment: it's not worked for me..any alternative solution

Comment: it's not work for me too